# What is "Host IP 2" in Goddady glue records manager?

Tags: domain-name-system, glue-record

Until now when we set a new glue records in Godaddy we add only one IP address to the "Host IP 1:" section.
I want to ask what can I set in the other fields (Host IP 2,Host IP 3 etc)?

Until I used NS1,NS2,NS3 why do I need 3 different IP's for NS1?
http://s13.postimage.org/vpv0b6lyv/glue_records.jpg

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can set more then one IP address for your authoritative nameserver, so they should all point to your nameserver (if it has more then one IP,...).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records) seems to confirm it is possible to set multiple IP addresses for one glue record.

I have never used more then one, but it seems to be possible.

I am not 100% sure about the Godaddy, and I would check with its's support, since they may be using the fields for something else.

Comment: That's correct. This is in case the host has more than one IP address. The most common case would be if you had an IPv4 address and an IPv6 address. But it could also be used if the host had two IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Yes, I know it's using IPv6 but why someone will like to add more IP's to the same server? I think about load balance (round robin style)

Comment: Other posibility is link redundancy (two links, two providers, two IPs)

Answer (score 0):

The More number of IP's are for the redundancy like in case of cloud servers. Generally you will have two ip's ipv4 or ipv6 for an ordinary vps and not more than that.

so it is better to create ns1.yourdomain.com and ns2.yourdomain.com rather than using two for the same nameserver.

Comment: I know I need NS1 and NS2 but why do I need NS3 or NS4? According to what you are saying I can add more IP's to NS2 and not build NS3 or 4. But If you look other companies name server like Godaddy and Google you will see they are using 3 and 4 so I still don't understand what it is. thanks

Comment: If you have more than two nameservers that you would like to list, they allow you to do that. You don't *need* them, but in some cases they are nice to have.

Comment: What do you mean by "nice to have"? If all the big company use NS3 and NS4 I believe there is a reason for that. You are saying that I can use "Host IP 2" in NS2 do do that?

Comment: @Noamway: Actually when you have multiple websites you can use ns1 and ns2 for say atleast 10 websites and ns3 ns4 for the other 10. Here the "10" is only an example, you can use as many sites as you want.

As David Schwartz suggested, it would be better if any other ip's have issues.

Please note that. Multiple nameservers can be used for mainly two things.

To show some behaviour of IP failover
To distribute the sites onto different nameservers.

If you have "lots" of sites like GoDaddy and other guys, then you need more nameservers to direct the traffic without any issues.

Comment: Thanks but I still not understand why to use NS3 and NS4 instead of using the Host IP 2,3,4,5 etc?

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting providers use only one IP per nameserver and like GoDaddy many hosting panels don't have the multiple IP thing. There is not much difference between using the two combinations.

> If you use NS1- two/three or more IP's then the request goes to all ip's and it will get your details through any one ip randomly(the one that works)
>
> If you use NS1- IP1  NS2 - IP2 then the requests go to two nameservers and the data will be obtained from the nameservers.

In case you have both ipv4 and ipv6 then you can use IPv4 and IPv6 on one nameserver, so that both connections are accepted for both types on one nameserver itself.

It doesn't make an BIG difference between these two,so there is no need to worry much about it. Practically you don't have or need a number of IP's unless you are a hosting company

GoDaddy panel is huge and supports IPv4 and IPv6 IP's for consideration of failover issues and other stuff.

If you want to test anything, then you can do it by using these two combinations and see the difference in website dns. you can test your ip's for error using pingdom like tools.